# How do I get Jinja2 to automatically squash all extraneous HTML whitespace?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

Is there a way to avoid having to do this?

```
{{-''-}}  <h2>{{- title -}}</h2>
{{-''-}}  <div class="blah">
{{-''-}}    {{- blah -}}
{{-''-}}    <div class="ha">
{{-''-}}       {{- text -}}
{{-''-}}    </div>
{{-''-}}  </div>
```

Comment: [Jinja2 HTMLcompress](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2-htmlcompress)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From comments:**

There's a Jinja2 extension called HTMLCompress. Its [Github page](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2-htmlcompress).

Follow the instructions to install it and then wrap parts of markup you want to compress in `{% strip %}` block:

```
{% strip %}
<div>
    Whitespace will be removed
</div>
{% endstrip %}
```